# Public Google Script doesn't run from a chrome extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google script which modifies the content of a google spreadsheet (it's not the final script of course), but I have a problem to run this simple script from a google chrome extension. 
Here is the script attached to my spreadsheet :

```
function insertData(parameters) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THE_URL_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET)
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(parameters.data1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(parameters.data2);
}
```

I deployed this script both as a web app (execute as me + access to everyone, even anonymous) and as an executable API (access to anyone).

Then I tried this JS script to run my google script, from a google chrome extension, using this code that I got from an google chrome extension example:

```
sendDataToExecutionAPICallback: function() {
    post({  'url': 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run',
            'callback': obj.executionAPIResponse,
            'token': 'MY_GENERATED_TOKEN'
            'request': {
                'function': 'insertData',
                'parameters': {                 
                    'data1': 'ok1 from script',
                    'data2': 'ok2 from script'
                },
                'devMode': true
            }
        });
}, 

executionAPIResponse: function(response){
    var obj = this;
    var info;
    if (response.response.result.status == 'ok'){
        info = 'Data has been entered';
    } else {
        info = 'Error...';
    }
    obj.displayMessage(info);
}
```

And I have this post function :

```
function post(options) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // JSON response assumed. Other APIs may have different responses.
            options.callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
            console.log('post', xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', options.url, true);
    // Set standard Google APIs authentication header.
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + options.token);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.request));
}
```

And when I call the `sendDataToExecutionAPICallback` function, I got this auth error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

**EDIT1:**
After generating a token, and added it to my code, I have this error:

```
 "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

Comment: From [documantation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run): This method **requires authorization with an OAuth 2.0 token** that includes at least one of the scopes listed in the Authorization section; script projects that do not require authorization cannot be executed through this API.

Comment: thanks ! I generated a token and I adapted the code (I edited it above), but now i have another error (error 403 : The caller does not have permission).

Comment: Make sure you have generated token with ALL scopes that are used in your script file (you can see all of them in File > Project properties, Scopes tab)

Comment: If you are going to leave the settings at: `access to everyone, even anonymous`, then there is no point in using OAuth, it's not needed.

Comment: I can understand that you want to run ``insertData()`` in GAS. But you are deploying both Web Apps and executable API. And it seems that your current script uses the executable API. Can I ask you about the method you want to use? By this, I think that your script can be modified.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I activated both web app and API because the API didn't work so I tried the web app. But I don't know which one is best for my need. I want to make a remote call on my insertData function. I don't really have a preference on the method and if there's something simpler I'll take it :) I'm sure I'm close to solve it ^^

Comment: I'm sorry. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow didn't make me notice your reply. If you reply to the specific users at comment with several users, please use "@username". So I'm sorry for my late response. I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to propose two methods. Please choose one of them.

### Method 1: [Execution API (Method: scripts.run of Apps Script API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/)

In order to run the functions using Execution API, please carry out the following flow.

1. Create a project (standalone or bound script).
2. Copy and paste your GAS script to the project. In this case, your GAS script was not modified.
3. [Deploy API executable.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_1_deploy_the_script_as_an_api_executable) As a sample, choose "Only myself" as "Who has access to the script"
4. Enable Apps Script API at API console.
5. Using the save button, save the project on the script editor. This is an important point. By this, the scripts are reflected to the deployed execution API.
6. Retrieve access token from client ID and client secret of this project.

   - Please include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` in the scopes. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` might not be used for this situation.

Please use the retrieved access token to the following modified script.

Javascript :

```
sendDataToExecutionAPICallback: function() {
  post({
    'url': 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run',
    'callback': obj.executionAPIResponse,
    'token': 'MY_GENERATED_TOKEN',
    'request': {
      'function': 'insertData',
      'parameters': [{
        'data1': 'ok1 from script',
        'data2': 'ok2 from script',
      }],
      'devMode': true,
    }
  });
},

executionAPIResponse: function(response) {
  var info;
  if (!response.error) {
    info = 'Data has been entered';
  } else {
    info = 'Error...';
  }
  obj.displayMessage(info);
},

function post(options) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // JSON response assumed. Other APIs may have different responses.
      options.callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    } else if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
      console.log('post', xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('POST', options.url, true);
  // Set standard Google APIs authentication header.
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + options.token);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.request));
}
```

#### Note :

- In my environment, this modified script works. But if in your environment, this didn't work, could you please try the method 2?

### Method 2: Web Apps

From your question and comments, I'm worried that the access token might not be able to be used. So I would like to also propose the method using Web Apps. In this case, you can run the function without the access token. But the password key to run is used at the payload.

When you use this, please deploy Web Apps as `"Execute the app as:" : Me` and `"Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous`. If you want to know the detail information of Web Apps, please check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

In this sample script, it doesn't use `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + options.token);` of `post()`.

The modified script is as follows. Please put GAS to the script editor which deploys Web Apps.

GAS :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var p = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  if (p.password == 'samplePassword') {
    insertData(p.parameters);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("error");
  }
}

function insertData(parameters) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THE_URL_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(parameters.data1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(parameters.data2);
}
```

Javascript :

```
sendDataToExecutionAPICallback: function() {
  post({
    'url': 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec', // URL of Web Apps
    'callback': obj.executionAPIResponse,
    'request': {
      'parameters': {
        'data1': 'ok1 from script',
        'data2': 'ok2 from script'
      },
      'password': 'samplePassword',
    }
  });
}, 
executionAPIResponse: function(response) {
  var info;
  if (response == 'ok') {
    info = 'Data has been entered';
  } else {
    info = 'Error...';
  }
  obj.displayMessage(info);
},

function post(options) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // JSON response assumed. Other APIs may have different responses.
      options.callback(xhr.responseText);
    } else if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
      console.log('post', xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('POST', options.url, true);
  // Set standard Google APIs authentication header.
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.request));
}
```

#### Note :

- If you use Web Apps, after copied and pasted the GAS script to the script editor, please redeploy Web Apps as a new version. By this, the latest script is reflected.

In my environment, I could confirm that both methods worked.

Comment: thanks Tanaike, the second method did work, but with a GET request (i have a cross-domain error with the POST, but since it worked with the GET i didn't check further). Thanks you !

Comment: @Julian Le Calvez Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your issue was solved. I will also test other ways in the future. When I got it, I would like to propose here.

Comment: sure, go ahead ;)